# Transistor with S250 marking

Tags: transistors, markings

does anyone knows what type of transistor this is:
[image]

DGS
S250
PH1d

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

Comment: I want to say "BS250", but you're the only one that can put your multimeter on the device.

Comment: PH1 sounds like Philips to me and BS250 is a highly probable candidate. http://wyxs.net/web/wiiscan/wiiscan/BS250.pdf Can you measure if it's an NMOS?

Comment: DGS is for Drain Gate Source so it is a type of MOSFET. As Ignacio said being a BS250, I'm skeptical why they omitted that first letter. Counterfeit part?

Comment: @Bradman: The 'S' is very probably a manufacturer logo (such as Siliconix) and the 250 is a short form name for the part as etched.

Comment: Checking the pinouts of BS250, it's different to the on in the image. Also why are the markings printed so horribly? They don't align to the case. And that Logo looks really lazy.

Comment: @Bradman175: are you sure its different? I just checked the BS250 datasheet and the DGS markings are in the same order as the BS250 pinout.

Comment: @winny: using the BS250 pinout, MM in diode mode, negative to S and positive to D, I have 0.56V so it can't be a P-MOSFET...

Comment: @winny: oups I got it wrong... if I have 0.56V on the conditions of my previous comment that means it can be a P-MOSFET, it is the voltage drop in the internal diode. How can I be sure it is really a P-MOSFET?

Comment: @PedroNF Can you draw your findings in a picture? Can you bias it with a voltage source and resistor and see if you can switch it (use a resistor in series with the gate as well, in case it isn't a gate). Then you can see if it's BJT or MOSFET as well as other useful things like Vgs.

Comment: @PedroNF please show me the datasheet link you used.

Comment: @Bradman175: I used the link you sent. In the datasheet image you have the view from below that corresponds to the GDS markings on the case.

Comment: @PedroNF ok yes you are right. I was looking at other datasheet and they were backwards. Seems like different manufacturers have different pinouts.

Comment: I just made a quick film of my test... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXmQ4TlnDOg

Comment: I just made a quick video of my test here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXmQ4TlnDOg I also tried later with a 1Kohm pullup resistor on the gate and it was working better, a short of the gate to ground was conducting and when I removed the sort to ground then it stopped conducting. So it looks like a P-MOSFET so thats probably a BS250.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a BS250 P-MOSFET. Here's one with similar markings at [bg-electronics.de](http://bg-electronics.de/shop/product_info.php/products_id/1880)

[image]